# DataWeave Transformer help in coding

Tags: dataweave

I have this as an input: `"keys":[{"key":"key1","value":"testKey1"},{"key":"Key2","value":"testKey2"}]`

What I am trying to do is to get this output in json format:

```
   { "key1": "testKey1",
     "key2":testKey2}
```

I am trying with the DataWeave transformer in mule:

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
 ---
{
price: payload.price,
"": payload.keys filter $.value !=null   
}
```

but it displays this:

```
"": [
{
  "value": "key1",
  "key": "testKey1"
},
{
  "value": "key2",
  "key": "testKey12"
}
]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you share the complete input, as your dataweave contains payload.price but the code snippet does not contain price

Comment: Seems your input and the output is same . Can you explain what is that you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following message snippet

```
    {
        "keys":
        [
            {
                "key":"key1",
                "value":"testKey1"},
            {
                "key":"Key2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I Have transformed using the below Dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
    keys: payload.keys map {
        key: $.key,
        value: $.value
    }
}
```

The response is as below. When the Values is not available then the value does not appear in the response

```
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "key": "key1",
          "value": "testKey1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Key2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**Input:**

```
{
  "keys":[
    {
     "key":"key1",
     "value":"value1"
    },
    {
     "key":"key2",
     "value":null
    },
    {
     "key":"key3",
     "value":"value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Dw script:**

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
{
  (payload.keys filter $.value !=null map {
     ($.key): $.value
  })
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```